# What does this method work with instanceof?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, equals, instanceof

i want to know how does this method works? Especially this part of code "((Book) o).getId()"

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o instanceof Book){
        return id == ((Book) o).getId();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If `o` is an instance of `Book`, it casts `o` to `Book` and gets its ID. What aspect is confusing you?

Comment: Look up "casting". You get an `Object` parameter, check if it is of type `Book` (using `instanceof`), and if it is you cast it to `Book` so you can call a `Book` method (`getId()`) on it.

Comment: It's effectively shorthand for `Book b = (Book) o;` `return id == b.getId();` An `Object` doesn't have the method `getId()` but `Book` does. `o instanceof Book` is there to ensure that `o` is of type `Book` or is a subtype of `Book` prior to casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o instanceof Book){ 
        return id == ((Book) o).getId(); 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

The method is passed an object, `instanceof` checks if the object passed into the method is of type `Book`.

If the object is of type `Book` then it enables you to safely cast the object to a `Book`.

Now the object is a `Book` - you are able to use the methods that the `Book` class has.

If the `Book` object `o` has the same value as `id` - it will return `true` else `false`.

If the object is not a book, it will return `false` as a default.

Answer (score 0):

First, the if statement verify if the variable **o** is an instance of Book class.

```
if (o instanceof Book)
```

Second, if **o** is a Book then we can cast it into a Book.
The code below return an Book object:

```
Book myVar = (Book) o;
```

And third, we can call Book methods in **myVar**. For example:

```
myVar.getId()
```

The code you posted do all this in one line. Cast, call a Book method and return a response.

Answer (score -1):

The `instanceof` syntax checks if the first object implements or extends the second object. If it does, it returns true. Then, since it **is** a book, it gets the ID of the object, which is a book.